# SQLite not utilizing full system resources during slow SELECT queries

Tags: performance, sqlite, concurrency

I'm performing some select queries with SQLite. The columns are already indexed.

Queries are in the format:

```
SELECT stuff 
FROM table 
WHERE haystack LIKE "%needle%"
```

I'm also loading the db into memory by running `RESTORE FROM my_db.db` and this seems to be working (used memory goes up)

The problem is - queries like the above still take a long time (close to 100ms), and I need to run a lot of them (thousands at a time), which means the results take up to several minutes to arrive.

However while the queries are running, I see a very low CPU usage - around 25-35% on average on all cores.

I think SQLite might be throttling its own performance somehow and not using all of the CPU.

Is there a way to get it to not throttle, and to utilize the full system resources so queries are faster?

Thanks.

Comment: `LIKE "%needle%"` can never use a index so it would become the full table scan annyway, you should consider using [full string search](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) and use full text indexes

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for that link - it looks like with that one, you have to create a virtual table and all data has to be inserted into it. Can that be done just once or does it have to be done every time? I have a lot of data - inserting it all into the virtual table would take a long time. I can't have that done with every startup.

Comment: *"I have a lot of data - inserting it all into the virtual table would take a long time. I can't have that done with every startup. "* lots of data is in the GB - TB scale (that's mine opinion) which i doubt you have here as SQLite was able to table scan in less then 100 ms unless the timing off 100 ms you mentioned was run on the memory..

Comment: *"inserting it all into the virtual table would take a long time. I can't have that done with every startup."* Then you need to look for a other RDMS like MySQL or PostgreSQL instead of using a embedded database like SQLite

Comment: I have about a GB of data haha. I think mysql would take about that much time with that data too. Is there no way to speed up the full table scan since I do most of the CPU idle @RaymondNijland ?

Comment: *"Is there no way to speed up the full table scan since I do most of the CPU idle"* Most likely not as most likely the CPU is waiting on the disk to fetch the data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland But I'm loading the db to memory using `RESTORE FROM my_db.db` and using `sqlite::memory` as the location of the db